# can batman.js be used with express?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, node.js, batman.js

I'm currently using Backbone.js for my webapp but I just read about [batman.js](http://batmanjs.org/) and I like the features it has to offer. However, I want to know if it integrates with express or am I stuck with the batman server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent a day putting together a boilerplate application, because I wanted to do the same thing, and it didn't seem very clear how to get started. [Batman-Express](https://github.com/austintaylor/batman-express)

Answer (score 2):

Batman will work with any server so will be fine with Express. In fact I've read that the seerver side of Batman isn't ready yet so you'd need to use it with something else on the sever for the time being anyway